# calculate avg time in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

i have a table with datetime, i need to find the avg of the time. i tried CASE statement but it gave me an error *Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator.*

```
select * from datestime

dates
2015-11-23 15:05:40.923
2015-11-23 15:05:43.610
2015-11-23 15:05:45.790
2015-11-23 15:05:48.293
```

first I split the colum into two column date and time

```
"select convert(date,dates,104) as date,convert(time,dates,108) as time from datestime"
```

then use CASE To calculate the avg of time.

```
;with avgtime as(
select convert(date,dates,104) as date,convert(time,dates,108) as time from datestime)
select avg(time) from avgtime
```

please help me to find the avg time

Comment: The question makes no sense to me. What do you call avg of time?

Comment: An average of absolute time like that makes no sense, do you really mean the midpoint between the min and max date within your date window?

Comment: If it's not the midpoint, can you give us some examples? So, what is the expected result given your sample data? Could the data extend over multiple days? What is the average of 1am, 2am and 11pm?

Comment: datetime column was split into two column as date one column and time one column. Now i was to calculate the avg time, substrate time etc i want to use different aggregate function on time. but it is throwing an error was using aggregate function --error msg "Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator"

Comment: @DheerajJain - the problem is, it's not at all clear what operation you want to perform. As other commenters above have pointed out, the concept of an "average" of time isn't a well defined one (if it was, one might expect the AVG operator to perform it). So, before your question can be answered, you need to describe what operation you want performed. Just repeating "average" doesn't help us to read your mind. As I suggested, one way to help would be to give some samples *and* what results you would expect to be computed for those samples.

Comment: i think i got it this time

Comment: ;with avgtime as(
select convert(date,dates,104) as date,convert(time,dates,108) as time from datestime)
select date,
  cast(cast(avg(cast(CAST(time as datetime) as float)) as datetime) as time) AvgTime
from avgtime
group by date;

Comment: 2015-11-23 15:05:44.6530000
2015-11-30 16:29:18.2230000

Answer (score 0):

You can get the midpoint between the start/end date in the range by doing this:

```
declare @start datetime = '2015-12-01T10:00:00'
declare @finish datetime = '2015-12-01T11:00:00'

print dateadd( second, ( datediff( second, @start, @finish ) / 2 ), @start )
```